# Is it possible to split up a GitHub workflow such that each step has a separate badge?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am relatively new to GitHub workflows and testing. I am working in a private GitHub repository with a dozen colleagues. We want to avoid using services like CircleCI for the time being and see how much we can do with just the integrated GitHub actions, since we are unsure about the kind of access a third party service would be getting to the repo.

Currently, we have two workflows (each one tests the same code for a separate Python environment) that get triggered on push or pull request in the master branch.

The steps of the workflow are as follows (the full workflow yml file is given at the bottom):

1. Install Anaconda
2. Create the conda environment (installing dependencies)
3. Patch libraries
4. Build a 3rd party library
5. Run python unit tests

It would be amazing to know immediately which part of the code failed given some new pull requests. Right now, every aspect of the codebase gets tested by a single python file `run_tests.py`. I was thinking of splitting up this file and creating a workflow per aspect I want to test separately, but then I would have to create a whole new environment, patch the libraries and build the 3rd party library every time I want to conduct a single test. These tests already take quite some time.

My question is now: is there any way to avoid doing that? Is there a way to build everything on the Linux server and re-use that, so that they don't need to be rebuilt every test? Is there a way to display a badge per python test that fails/succeeds, so that we can give more information than just "everything passed" or "everything failed". Is such a thing better suited for a service like CircleCI (or other recommendations are also welcome)?

Here is the full yml file for the workflow for the Python 3 environment. The Python2 one is identical except for the anaconda environment steps.

```
name: (Python 3) install and test

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash -l {0}

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Install Anaconda3 and update conda package manager
      - name: Install Anaconda3
        run: |
          wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh --quiet
          bash Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/conda3-env-py3
          source ~/conda3-env-py3/bin/activate
          conda info
      # Updating the root environment. Install dependencies (YAML)
      # NOTE: The environment file (yaml) is in the 'etc' folder
      - name: Install ISF dependencies
        run: |
          source ~/conda3-env-py3/bin/activate
          conda-env create --name isf-py3 --file etc/env-py3.yml --quiet
          source activate env-py3
          conda list
          
      # Patch Dask library
      - name: Patch dask library
        run: |
          echo "Patching dask library."
          source ~/conda3-env-py3/bin/activate
          source activate env-py3
          cd installer
          python patch_dask_linux64.py
          conda list
      # Install pandas-msgpack
      - name: Install pandas-msgpack
        run: |
          echo "Installing pandas-msgpack"
          git clone https://github.com/abast/pandas-msgpack.git
          # Applying patch to pandas-msgpack (generating files using newer Cython)
          git -C pandas-msgpack apply ../installer/pandas_msgpack.patch
          source ~/conda3-env-py3/bin/activate
          source activate env-py3
          cd pandas-msgpack; python setup.py install
          pip list --format=freeze | grep pandas
      # Compile neuron mechanisms
      - name: Compile neuron mechanisms
        run: |
          echo "Compiling neuron mechanisms"
          source ~/conda3-env-py3/bin/activate
          source activate env-py3
          pushd .
          cd mechanisms/channels_py3; nrnivmodl
          popd
          cd mechanisms/netcon_py3; nrnivmodl
          
      # Run tests
      - name: Testing
        run: |
          source ~/conda3-env-py3/bin/activate
          source activate env-py3
          export PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)"
          dask-scheduler --port=38786 --dashboard-address=38787 &
          dask-worker localhost:38786 --nthreads 1 --nprocs 4 --memory-limit=100e15 &
          python run_tests.py
```

Many thanks in advance

Tried:
Building everything in a single github workflow, testing everything in the same workflow.

Expected:
Gaining information on specific steps that failed or worked. Displaying this information as a badge on the readme page.

Actual result:
Only the overall success status can be displayed as badge. Only the success status of "running all tests" is available.

Comment: Not tried this, but you might be able to define each part as a reuseable workflow and then call them all from a 'master' workflow. You can then (hopefully!) have a badge for each reusable part? Docs on reusable workflows are here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#creating-a-reusable-workflow